Form Post Action not working with authorize.net api
Am trying to integrate Authorize.net into my web-app and trying to use their acceptHosted for short the hosted payment page however am have trouble doing it. I have tried htlm and failed then tried react and sofar failed as well:
Heres my react code:
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
     const App = () => {
      const [token, setToken] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get the token from the URL
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const tokenFromUrl = urlParams.get('token');
    setToken(tokenFromUrl);
  }, []);

  const handleContinueClick = () => {
    if (token) {
      console.log(token);
      // Submit the form
      document.getElementById('formAuthorizeNetTestPage').submit();
    } else {
      console.error('Token is missing. Unable to submit the form.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: '100vh' }}>
      <form
        method="post"
        action="https://accept.authorize.net/payment/payment"
        id="formAuthorizeNetTestPage"
        name="formAuthorizeNetTestPage"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="token" id="tokenInput" value={token} />
        <button type="button" id="btnContinue" onClick={handleContinueClick} style={{          backgroundColor: 'black', color: 'white', padding: '10px 20px', border: 'none', cursor: 'pointer', fontSize: '16px', borderRadius: '5px' }}>
          Continue to payment
        </button>
        </form>
       </div>
       );
       };

       export default App;

When it odoes the redirect, its saying Invalid or Missing token.
However if the token value is static like its there before the page load i.e i hard code it. everything works fine.
Idk what am doing wrong. somebody help please
A redirect to authorize with a working payment form

does console.log(token); output the "correct token"?

@JaromandaX yes
